# While loop not working properly in tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tkinter, while-loop

I am currently having an issue where I am trying to run a while loop inside a tkinter window. It waits until the while loop finishes for it to actual show the window. What I want to happen is for the window to come up, and then the while loop will begin. After research I found that it is something to do with the root.mainloop() function, but I am not sure how to change it.

```
#creates new window
root = Tk()

#makes backdrop picture of map
C = Canvas(root, bg="black", height=780, width=1347)
C.grid(row=0,column=0)
filename = PhotoImage(file = "map4.png")
background_label = Label(root, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

totalDeaths = 0
totalCases = 0
totalPopulation = 15000
dayCount = 0

#loops until total deaths = population
while totalDeaths < totalPopulation:
    totalDeaths += 1
    time.sleep(1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It will take your while loop 15000 seconds  (a little over 4 hours) to finish.

Comment: I've just done this to make the code easier to read. There is a complicated function which I have replaced with the line totalDeaths+= 1

Comment: We can only see the code you put in the question. We have no way of knowing what code is on your computer. The code you posted sleeps for over four hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop is working exactly as designed. You have in effect asked it to sleep for 15,000 seconds so that's what it is doing. While it is sleeping, tkinter is unable to refresh the display or process events of any type.

When creating GUIs, a rule of thumb is that you should never have a large `while` loop in the same thread as the GUI. The GUI already has an infinite loop running all the time.

So, the first step is to move the code which is inside your loop to a function. In a UI it's often good to separate the UI code from non-UI code, so in this case I recommend two functions: one to do the calculation and one to update the display. This will make it easier to replace either the UI or the method of calculation without having to rewrite the whole program. It will also make it easier to test the calculation function with a unit test.

So, let's start with a function that calculates the deaths. Based on comments to other answers, it appears that you have a complicated formula for doing that but simply incrementing the total is good enough for a simulation.

```
def update_deaths():
    global totalDeaths
    totalDeaths += 1
```

Next, you need a way to display those deaths. The code you posted doesn't have any way to do that, so this solution requires the addition of a `Label` to show current deaths. How you do it for real is up to you, but the following code illustrates the general principle:

```
death_label = Label(...)
...
def update_display():
    global totalDeaths
    death_label.configure(text=f"Total Deaths: {totalDeaths}")
```

The third piece of the puzzle is the code to simulate your `while` loop. Its job is to update the deaths and then update the display every second until the entire population has died.

We do that with the `after` method which can schedule a function to be run in the future. By using `after` rather than sleep, it allows `mainloop` to be able to continue to process events such as button clicks, key presses, requests to update the display, etc.

```
def simulate_deaths():
    global totalDeaths
    global totalPopulation
    
    update_deaths()
    update_display()

    if totalDeaths < totalPopulation:
        root.after(1000, simulate_deaths)
```

If you call this function once at the start of your program, it will continue to be called once a second until the condition is met.

The `after` method returns an identifier, which you can use to cancel the function before its next iteration. If you save that in a global variable (or instance variable if you're using classes), you can stop the simulation by calling `after_cancel` with that identifier.

For example:

```
def simulate_deaths():
    global after_id
    ...
    after_id = root.after(1000, simulate_deahts)
    

def stop_simulation():
    root.after_cancel(after_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for this Bryan! An excellent explanation of how to approach the situation, and I can't thank you enough for it. Hope you have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `sleep` with `tkinter`. Instead, use method called `after`:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.total_deaths = 0
        self.label = tk.Label(text='')
        self.label.pack()
        self.update_deaths()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_deaths(self):
        self.total_deaths += 1
        self.label.configure(text=f'Total deaths: {self.total_deaths}')
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_deaths)

App()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I've heavily simplified my code (classes, buttons, labels) so I don't know if this would help. If I was to edit the code I wrote earlier to make it more contextual, would that be okay?

Comment: No. You need to post here [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your while loop is never ending since `totalDeaths` will always be smaller than `totalPopulation`

You could have something like this:

```
while totalDeaths < totalPopulation:
    if somebodyDies:
        totalDeaths+=1   

    else:
        continue
```

Comment: I tried to make it easier to read so got rid of a complicated function so I've edited it now to make logical sense

Comment: yup was just creating a template... turns out he just dumbened it down a bit anyway, that wasnt the problem